# Excel : Create for each row (in a spreadsheet) a .xml file (using VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, transform

I built a code that creates a .xml file for each row, for example, the below spreadsheet
[image: Example: Rows to transform]

The following code works fine except for one case when **ResetDate** has the same value for more than 1 row.

The VBA code (I'm not an expert)

```
Sub testXLStoXML()
 sTemplateXML = _
        "<?xml version='1.0'?>" + vbNewLine + _
        "<E>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   <ResetDate>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   </ResetDate>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   <ValueDate>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   </ValueDate>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   <MaturityD>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   </MaturityD>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   <Rate>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   </Rate>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   <Quantity>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   </Quantity>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   <ID>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   </ID>" + vbNewLine + _
        "</E>" + vbNewLine

 Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
 doc.async = False
 doc.validateOnParse = False
 doc.resolveExternals = False

 With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
  lLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

  For lRow = 2 To lLastRow
   sFile = Format(.Cells(lRow, 1).Value, "DD-MMM-YY")
   sBirthdate = Format(.Cells(lRow, 2).Value, "DD-MMM-YY")
   sAmount = Format(.Cells(lRow, 3).Value, "DD-MMM-YY")
   sRate = .Cells(lRow, 4).Value
   sQuantity = .Cells(lRow, 5).Value
   sID = .Cells(lRow, 6).Value
   doc.LoadXML sTemplateXML
   doc.getElementsByTagName("ResetDate")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(ResetDate)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("ValueDate")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(ValueDate)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("MaturityD")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(MaturityD)
  doc.getElementsByTagName("Rate")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sRate)
  doc.getElementsByTagName("Quantity")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sQuantity)
  doc.getElementsByTagName("ID")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sID)
   doc.Save sFile
  Next

 End With
End Sub
```

[image: Output 10 files, output expected 11 files]

As you can see I get as output just 1 file for the date:

> [image]

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: On which line does the error occur? Also since you are saving by the reset date, don't you expect an error if you are saving with an existing file name?

Comment: Hi, @AAA I don't see any error, the VBA runs without issues. I can't see any message like overwriting/replacing an existing file,  following your question now my question would be: " can I save the files, not by ResetDate? saving them like file_1, file_2, file_3,..., file_n?" thanks for your message.

Comment: As mentioned by @AAA, You're using the following code to determine your filename `sFile = Format(.Cells(lRow, 1).Value, "DD-MMM-YY")`, which references column 1, in which your `ResetDate1 is contained, hence two files will have the same name :0)

Comment: Hello @AAA sorry for the late reply, yesterday I didn't time to look at it. It's working fine now, fixed, thanks for your interest and your time. Regards!

Comment: @LorenzoCastagno, if it worked for you, you should [upvote and mark as accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @AAA, of course, that was the first thing that I tried this morning, but I can't vote because I'm under 15 points of reputation... update: done!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete `doc.Save sFile` and replace with the following code:

```vb
Dim x as Long
x = Application.CountIf(.Range("A2:A" & lrow), .Cells(lRow, 1))
If  x > 1 Then doc.Save sFile & "_" & x Else doc.Save sFile
```

**So your amended code** would be:

```vb
Sub testXLStoXML()
Dim x as Long
sTemplateXML = _
    "<?xml version='1.0'?>" + vbNewLine + _
    "<E>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   <ResetDate>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   </ResetDate>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   <ValueDate>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   </ValueDate>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   <MaturityD>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   </MaturityD>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   <Rate>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   </Rate>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   <Quantity>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   </Quantity>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   <ID>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   </ID>" + vbNewLine + _
    "</E>" + vbNewLine

Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
doc.async = False
doc.validateOnParse = False
doc.resolveExternals = False

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    lLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For lRow = 2 To lLastRow
        sFile = Format(.Cells(lRow, 1).Value, "DD-MMM-YY")
        sBirthdate = Format(.Cells(lRow, 2).Value, "DD-MMM-YY")
        sAmount = Format(.Cells(lRow, 3).Value, "DD-MMM-YY")
        sRate = .Cells(lRow, 4).Value
        sQuantity = .Cells(lRow, 5).Value
        sID = .Cells(lRow, 6).Value
        doc.LoadXML sTemplateXML
        doc.getElementsByTagName("ResetDate")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(ResetDate)
        doc.getElementsByTagName("ValueDate")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(ValueDate)
        doc.getElementsByTagName("MaturityD")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(MaturityD)
        doc.getElementsByTagName("Rate")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sRate)
        doc.getElementsByTagName("Quantity")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sQuantity)
        doc.getElementsByTagName("ID")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sID)
        x = Application.CountIf(.Range("A2:A" & lrow), .Cells(lRow, 1))
        If  x > 1 Then doc.Save sFile & "_" & x Else doc.Save sFile
    Next lrow
End With

End Sub
```